# Not working my javascript onblur function

Tags: javascript, html, onblur, appendchild

I am having some problems with a javascipt function which I'm working on.

Here is what I am trying to do with the function:

I have a table element with a given value, and when there is a click on it, it calls my javasript function which is supose to appendChild an INPUT element with the value of the element, so the user can change that value. I want the INPUT element to call a function whit the `onblur()` event, so the modified value could be display again on the table element.

My problem is that the element does not respect the `onblur()` event. The function is executed right after the Input element is created, and does not wait to be an `onblur()` event.

Here is the code of the two functions:

```
var elemento = true;

function prueba(clave,cantidad) {
    if(elemento){
        var percent = document.getElementById('porciento' + clave);
        percent.innerHTML = "";
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute('type','text');
        input.setAttribute('size','5');
        input.setAttribute('value',cantidad);
        input.setAttribute('id','child'+clave);
        percent.appendChild(input);
        input.focus();
        child = document.getElementById("child" + clave);
        child.onblur = blurPrueba();
    }
}
function blurPrueba() {
    if(elemento)
        alert("Hello");
}
```

The alert is displayed without being an onblur()

Does anyone knows why this is happening???

Comment: create a fiddle so we can see it in action

Comment: Hi, I'm kind of new with this. How do I create a fiddle??

Comment: @mauguerra: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).  It's a site to test HTML/JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is: `child.onblur = blurPrueba()`, where you execute `blurPrueba` immediately. Should be a reference: `child.onblur = blurPrueba`

Changing the line, you tell the browser: "on blur for the child element, activate the `blurPrueba` function".

If you use `blurPrueba()` you activate the function and assign it's result to the blur event, `blurPrueba()` doesn't return anything. So your line actually says: "`onblur = undefined`"

In summary, if you want the browser to handle an event (here `blur`) you need to provide a *reference* to the handler function (here `blurPrueba`).

Comment: Hi @kooiInc, I am not sure if I understood you. I shoul put again the child.onblur=blurPrueba() again on the blurPrueba() function?

Comment: Just one thing is not very clear. What happens if I need to send some parameter to the function??

Comment: It's an event handler. You don't invoke it, the browser does.

Comment: @mauguerra: that's a different question. You could use closures and an anonymous function to pass some parameter to the handler function. See http://jsfiddle.net/BQNrk/ for a very basic example.

Answer (score 1):

Change

child.onblur = blurPrueba();

to

child.onblur = function(){blurPrueba()};